# Jquery ajax + php automatic email with POST request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, email

I have a program that randomly generates numbers and I want it to send an email if the value is X.

Everything else is working fine, but my email.php file doesn't send an email.

Here's my Jquery/ajax function where I 'call' email.php.

```js
function sendErrMsgPost(errMsg){
    $.ajax({
        url: "email.php",
        data: {
            message: errMsg
        },
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
            
            
    })
    .done(function(htmlString) {
        alert("Email sent!");
    })
        
    .fail(function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
        alert( "Sorry, there was a problem!" );
        console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
        console.log( "Status: " + status );
        console.dir( xhr );
    });
}
```

That piece alerts "email sent" so I guess it does the POST request correctly? However it doesn't give any error even though email is never sent. Is this because the problem is in email.php file?

I'm using cloud9 IDE for programming and I don't see any error messages in there. Can't locate php.ini and don't know how to make error messages visible.

Here's my email.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['message'])){
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    mail("example@gmail.com", "System Critical Condition", $message);
}
?>
```

Comment: post the html form for this

Comment: change `mail("example@gmail.com", "System Critical Condition", $message);` to `if(mail("example@gmail.com", "System Critical Condition", $message)){ echo "Mail is sent"; } else { echo "Error"; }` what does it show you? or an `else { echo "not set"; }` for `if(isset($_POST['message'])){...}` and php error reporting.

Comment: There's  no form. Site creates new random number every 5 seconds and if number is specific value it'll generate errormessage that's passed on to method that's in the post.

Comment: ok, you replied for my first comment; now for the second one I left.

Comment: Tried adding those in the code but the thing is.. I'm using Cloud9 as an IDE and I don't have a clue where I should look for those error messages that I just created. Ajax keeps updating my site all the time so it doesn't show any error on the site at least.

I'm fairly new with php.

Comment: @Dosentti if you apply Fred's changes, then it will echo "Mail is sent" or "Error" from PHP. In an ajax context, that value will be returned as the response from the ajax call. So in your `.done()` method, that text will be contained within `htmlString`, so you can log that to your browser console. P.S. Your Cloud9 instance should have a Terminal available where you can go looking for the PHP logs. P.P.S. Even if `mail` reports success, it doesn't guarantee that the mail will be delivered - see the "Return values" section here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: This might be of interest too - suggested ways to send mail from Cloud9 apps https://community.c9.io/t/how-can-i-send-email-from-my-app/1262

Comment: @ADyson Thanks a lot! I didn't realize it could be impossible to send an email from C9. 

I created a test form and at least my email.php file works. So since I don't have other environment to test in I guess I'll have to just trust that the whole thing works.